# Error while adding name in Excel Name Manager

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am getting an error(Error 1004:Application defined or object defined error) while adding name in Excel Name Manager using VBA

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SaveSelections", RefersToR1C1:=strRangeValue
```

The code works fine when the strRangeValue is of small length,but throws error for long values.Is there any character limit for the string value that is added to name manager directly?

Comment: strRangeValue should be range.

Comment: It's about 255 characters, IIRC. By the way, you are not using Name Manager here at all.

Comment: But my requirement is to add the strings valuse directly  to a named range

Comment: The limit is 255, but there are some workarounds, but it all depends how exactly does the strRangeValue look like, how do you build it, etc.

Comment: strRangeValue is added as:   strRangeValue="={""a"",""b"",""c"";""d"",""e"",""f""}"

Comment: It looks like you are adding constant array as a named range. To workaround string length limit you should be adding variant array instead of string. It should be easy to get it directly from a range.